# How to add loggers without actually touching the existing java files?

Tags: java, logging

I have a huge java project with millions of lines of code. However the code does not have sufficient logging. Is there any way to add loggers in all java files at method level ? Basically I want to log all the input parameters to a method. It can be in any technology.

Comment: maybe it is enough to change the log level? normally when you have logging you have log levels as INFO, DEBUG, ERROR... https://javapapers.com/log4j/log4j-levels/ change it for example to ALL to see everything being logged, if still there is no enough information then you will have to implement classes to log more information

Comment: If there are no loggers at the moment, what messages do you want to trigger?

Comment: It is always a good practice to add consolidated logs at a common place rather than multiple logs at individual class levels. The prior one decrease the i/o on servers where your application is running.

Comment: You can add log statements automatically (for example using AOP), however, you will not be happy with the result.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of technical debt.

Comment: I want to log all the input parameters to a method. However there is absolutely zero logging. One way is to use AOP. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Your code base is plain Java (SE) or JavaEE? There are a few options on Java EE to reduce the effort of adding logging...